# Best column type for huge numeric data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What's the best data type for storing numeric values
(like 1656659676159881372) in MariaDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DECIMAL](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/data-types/DECIMAL/) datatype for these values.

The maximum number of digits for `DECIMAL` is 65.

If you need numbers in the range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775808, you could use `bigint` instead.  Likewise, if you only need numbers in the range of -2147483648 to 2147483648, you could use a standard `int` datatype.